# Js date to string

Tags: javascript

I need after date subtraction return date in string format yyyy-mm-dd

```
const date = new Date();
const diff = date.setDate( date.getDate() - 10 );
```

adding toISOString() doesnt works because it's not a fuction

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Simpler solution (thank you, @Ivar). You can use  `toISOString` directly on `date`.

```
const date = new Date();

date.setDate( date.getDate() - 10 );

const iso_date = date.toISOString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const d = new Date();

const result = d.getFullYear() + "-" + d.getMonth() + "-" + d.getDate()

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const date = new Date();
const diff = date.setDate( date.getDate() - 10 );
const d = new Date(diff);
const result = d.getFullYear() + "-" + d.getMonth() + "-" + d.getDate();
```